# Is ‘switched on’ a prepositional verb?

Tags: adverbial-phrases, prepositional-verbs

He switched on a table lamp to banish the gloom of a winter afternoon.

1. Is ‘switched on’ a prepositional verb?
2. Is ‘To banish the gloom’ an infinitive phrase functioning as adverb, modifying the verb.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "switched on" is a phrasal verb meaning "activated". This type of phrasal verb is also known as a prepositional verb, because it includes a preposition.

Yes, the infinitive phrase "to banish the gloom" provides the reason he performed the action.

Comment: How to differentiate if it is phrasal verb or prepositional verb?

Comment: @Opel I have edited the answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

> *He switched on a table lamp to banish the gloom of a winter afternoon.*

*Switch* on *NP* (or *switch* NP *on*) is a verbal idiom. I would avoid the term 'phrasal verb' though; it's a misnomer and thoroughly misleading. It's not the whole expression "switch on" that is a verb, but just the word "switch".

Note that "on" is called a particle here since it can occur between the verb and its direct object, or follow the object: "He switched a table lamp on ...".

"To banish the gloom" is an infinitival clause functioning as a purpose adjunct in clause structure, where it modifies the verb phrase.